# Is there a way to write a function in R that writes a dataframe like in this script?

Tags: r, function, dataframe, spatial, spatial-data-frame

I wrote a script in R which reads a csv file to a dataframe, then manipulates that dataframe to create a new one.  The current script is as follows:

```
#read in the csv file for a node
node00D = read.csv("00D.csv")

#create a new data frame with the specific measurement we want to decrease file size
node00D_smaller = node00D[node00D$sensor=="BMP180",]

#remove the columns that we don't need
keeps = c("node_id","timestamp","parameter","value")
node00D = node00D_smaller[keeps]

#fix row names
rownames(node00D) = 1:nrow(node00D)

#convert the timestamp column from a factor to a date and then truncate to the hour
node00D$timestamp = as.POSIXlt(node00D$timestamp)
node00D$timestamp = trunc(node00D$timestamp,"hour")
rm(keeps,node00D_smaller)

#get average temperature for each hour
library(plyr)
node00D$timestamp = as.character(node00D$timestamp)
node00D_means = ddply(node00D, .(timestamp), summarize,
                      mean=round(mean(value),2))
node00D$timestamp = as.POSIXlt(node00D$timestamp)
node00D_means$timestamp = as.POSIXlt(node00D_means$timestamp)
write.csv(node00D_means,"00D_Edit.csv")

#load lat long data
latlong = read.csv("Node.Lat.Lon.csv")
node00D_means$Node = "00D"
node00D_means = merge(node00D_means,latlong,by="Node")
```

I have to do this for up to 100 nodes, and so I tried writing a function with argument 'node' which would perform this.  In this example, I would input getNodeData(00D).  However, when I do this there are issues actually creating the data frames.  The function runs but does not create any new objects.  Is there a way to turn this script into a function so that I can more easily perform it 100 times?

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like

```
fun1 <- function(node.num){

### (1). Load the data
  dat <- read.csv(paste0(node.num, ".csv"))
  dat_smaller <- dat[dat$sensor=="BMP180",]

### (2). Here proceed with your code and substitute node00D(_smaller) by dat(_smaller) ###
# ------------------------------------------------------------------- #  

### (3). Then define dat_mean and save the .csv 
  library(plyr)
  dat$timestamp=as.character(dat$timestamp)
  dat_means=ddply(dat,.(timestamp),summarize,mean=round(mean(value),2))
  dat$timestamp=as.POSIXlt(dat$timestamp)
  dat_means$timestamp=as.POSIXlt(dat_means$timestamp)
  write.csv(dat_means,paste0(node.num, "_Edit.csv"))

### (4). And similarly for lat long
  latlong=read.csv("Node.Lat.Lon.csv")
  dat_means$Node=node.num
  dat_means=merge(dat_means,latlong,by="Node")

}
```

Now this function is not returning anything, it is saving the `.csv` files though. However, if you want it to return something, e.g. `dat_means`, then you can add the line `return(dat_means)` before the function ends.

**Appendix**

Now to perform the above operation dynamically, you can for instance using a loop:

```
### (1.) First, create an object containing all your nodes, e.g.
nodes.vector <- c("00D", ...)

### (2.) Run a loop, or use one of the apply functions
for(k in seq_along(nodes.vector)){
  fun1(nodes.vector[k])
}
# Or
sapply(nodes.vector, fun1)
```

Now I don't know your data, but if the nodes are contained in `latlong$Node`, then you can set this to be your `dat.vector`.

Comment: Thank you so much!  Now, if I want to perform this function for 60 different node.nums, is there a way to do that with a for loop?  For example:
`for (i in latlong$Node) {
  paste0("node",i)=getNodeData(i)
}`

Comment: @NoahCohen-Harding See the edit for how to perform that for multiple nodes. PS: I am not sure what your aim is with that loop but you in that instance you should use `assign`, e.g. `assign(paste0("node",i),getNodeDate(i))` (I am assuming `getNodeDate` is an existing function).